# XML с параметрами (POST)

Tags: java, spring, post, rest

Можете пожалуйста пример какой подсказать для реализации post метода в контролере spring.
По условию контроллер, принимает на вход XML с параметрами.

Спасибо.

Comment: Что значит "принимает на вход XML с параметрами"?

Comment: как я понимаю это что то вроде consumes = MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "xml", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/xml")
public ResponseEntity<String> processXml(@RequestBody String request){ 
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Handled application/xml request. Request body was: " 
      + requestBody, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Но так же вам нужно указать в конфигурации спринга, что ваши входные и выходные данные нужно парсить в `XML`.